# How may inputs can i take in 1 line using Cin in C++?

Tags: c++

like
if `a`, `b` are variables
then

```
cin>>a>>b;
```

like this how many variables can I take with 1 `cin`.

Comment: There's no limit, but it becomes unreadable pretty quickly.

Comment: @molbdnilo what do you mean by unreadable. Can you explain it a little more

Comment: he meant that it will be hard for humans to read and understand code if the chain of `>>` is long. Note that code is written once and read +20 times, so human must be able to read code as much comfortable as it is possible.

Answer (score 7):

Fist some nitpicking on wording: There is only one [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin). It is an object of type `std::istream`. It has an `operator>>` that lets you read one thing at a time. As the operator returns a reference to `std::cin` you can chain as many calls as you like.

Consider that those two are doing the same thing:

```
 std::cin >> a;
 std::cin.operator>>(a);
```

Chaining is achieved by

```
 std::cin >> a >> b;
 std::cin.operator>>(a).operator>>(b);
```

Because each call to `operator>>` returns a reference to the stream, there is no limit on how many variables you can read in one statement:

```
 int a,b,c,d,e,f;
 std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e >> f;
```

Though already with 2 variables you should consider if maybe they belong into the same data structure

```
 struct a_and_b {
     int a;
     int b;
 };
```

Then you can provide an overload for the `operator>>`

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in,a_and_b& x) {
       in >> x.a;
       in >> x.b;
       return in;
};
```

And then use the much more readable:

```
a_and_b x;
std::cin >> x;
```

Comment: A really well explained anser +1. To be complete we probably should mention the ````std::istream_iterator````

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is unlimited. But usually people use loops to input more data from cin, it is more controllable.